# How do I update my app with a new build version?

Tags: swift, app-store

I already have an app published on the app store but I have made changes and want to submit a newer version. How do I do this? Do I have to make a complete new app version and enter every detail again?
What about the data inside the app will people who used my app lose all the data on the app?

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. To update an iOS app, you will need to re-use the exact same bundle ID as the previous version and increment / increase the version number. Same applies to subsequent builds submitted to App Store Connect.

1) In **Xcode** make sure to use the exact same bundle identifier (You can look it up on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com if you can't remember it)

2) Then set the Version to the new version. This does not need to be the exact same as on App Store Connect (which is the customer facing number), but I can only highly recommend using the same to not get confused.

2A) If you already have a build uploaded for the new version, you need to increment the build version as well. (i.e. if you have build 1.0.0, next one can be 1.0.1)

[image]

3) Create a new version of your app on **App Store Connect**. This can be done independently from your work in Xcode and you can even upload a new build even though there is no new version yet.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Any changes inside your build requires a new update for you app.

**How do I do this?**

First you have to add a new version in AppStore Connect. The only thing which is required is the text for the update i think, the rest is optional(Screenshots etc.).

After that you can upload a new version from Xcode (or Application Loader). 
- increase the build number of your build target
- archive your app and upload it to AppStore Connect.

After a while your build is available in AppStore Connect and you can add it to your new version and send it to review.

**What about the data inside the app will people who used my app lose all the data on the app?**

- Files in the documents directory will not be deleted if a user updates your app
- Data in the UserDefaults will also not deleted
- Files in the cache directory can be deleted every time